# If D is compact, then f(D) is compact? Is this true?

Tags: real-analysis

I don't think this is true because in order for something to be compact it must be closed and bounded.  I am pretty sure that if D is bounded then f(D) is bounded but when D is closed, it doesn't necessarily mean that f(D) is closed.

Editing to add Let f:D->R be continuous

Comment: What is your $f$? Does it satisfy injectivity and surjectivity?

Comment: $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ that sends $\frac1n$ to $n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and everything else to itself. Now if $f$ is continous instead...

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have suggested, this depends a lot on what $f$ is. If you supply no conditions, then you can say nothing about compactness of the image.

However, if $f$ is continuous, then the image will be compact. A better way to see this is not by describing compact sets as being closed and bounded, but by describing them in terms of finite open covers.

That is:

**Definition**: A set X is compact if for every open cover $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $X$ there exists a finite collection $\{i_1, \ldots, i_k\} \subset I$ such that $X \subset U_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_k}$.

This definition is more general (although equivalent for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^N$), and works better for this case here, since continuous functions are defined so that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open for open sets $V$ in the image.

It is now an important (but not too hard!) exercise to show that these two definitions together yield that $f(D)$ is compact for $D$ compact, $f$ continuous.

Comment: I edited to add to let f:D -> R be continuous.